# Splitting a string on an uppercase *or* lowercase letter

Tags: python, string

I have the following string:

```
foo = 'F9B2Z1F8B30Z4'
```

I split this string on upper-case `F`, as such:

```
chunks = ['F' + elem for elem in foo.split('F') if elem != '']
```

This gives me:

```
chunks
['F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']
```

But, now assume that one of the `F` characters is lowercase:

```
'F9B2Z1f8B30Z4'
```

Now, we get:

```
chunks = ['F' + elem for elem in foo.split('F') if elem != '']
chunks
['F9B2Z1f8B30Z4']
```

I'd like to be able to also split on lower-case `f`, such as:

```
chunks = ['F' + elem for elem in foo.split('F') if elem != '' <some other condition here>]
chunks
['F9B2Z1' 'f8B30Z4']
```

I'm somewhat hesitant to use `.replace()` because ***after doing the split*** I need to perform some tests on the resulting list of chunks (e.g. test whether the first character of each chunk is uppercase or lowercase... and it would be difficult to do that if I replace lowercase Fs with uppercase Fs).

What's the best way to split on uppercase or lowercase **without using RegEx**?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `re.split()` with a regular expression that matches upper or lower case.

Comment: @Barmar -- I asked, "What's the best way to split on uppercase or lowercase __without using RegEx__?"

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Why the restriction?\

Comment: Split on `F`, then split each of those parts on `f`.

Comment: @JohnGordon -- `chunks` is a list and I don't believe it's possible to split a list.  I'm not following you.  Are you suggesting that I split on `F` and assign to `chunks`, then split the resulting `chunks` (which is a list) on `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `enumerate`:

```
foo = 'F9B2Z1f8B30Z4'

indices = [n for n, i in enumerate(foo) if i.lower() == "f"]
[foo[i:j] for i, j in zip(indices, indices[1:] + [None])]
```

Output:

```
['F9B2Z1', 'f8B30Z4']
```